# Using a loop to open and process txt files with csv

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, syntax

I have data (mixed text and numbers in txt files) and I'd like to write a for loop that creates a list of lists, such that I can process the data from all the files using fewer lines.

So far I have written this:

```
import csv

path = (some path...)
files = [path + 'file1.txt',path + 'file2.txt', path + 
'file3.txt', ...]

for i in files:
    with open(i, 'r') as j:
        Reader = csv.reader(j)
        List = [List for List in Reader]
```

I think I overwrite `List` instead of creating a nested list, since I get `Reader` with size of 1 and a list that's with dimensions for one of the files.

My questions:

1. Given that the files may contain different line numbers, is it the right approach to save some lines of code? (What could be done better?)
2. I think the problem is in `[List for List in Reader]`, is there a way to change it so I don't overwrite `List`? Something like add to `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the list [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method to add to an existing `list`. Since `csv.reader` instances are iterable objects, you can just pass one of them to the method as shown below:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('./')
filenames = ['in_file1.txt', 'in_file2.txt']  # etc ...
List = []

for filename in filenames:
    with open(path / filename, 'r', newline='') as file:
        List.append(list(csv.reader(file)))

print(List)
```

**Update**

An even more succinct way to do it would be to use something called a "[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)":

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('./')
filenames = ['in_file1.txt', 'in_file2.txt']  # etc ...
List = [list(csv.reader(open(path / filename, 'r', newline='')))
            for filename in filenames]

print(List)
```

Comment: Good idea with Path. 
The List created is not a list of lists as requested and would make it hard to differentiate between files.

Comment: Oh…in that case I guess you want a list-of-lists-of-lists. See update. Also, yes, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) is often a good way to do things — I'm trying to get in the habit of using it instead of [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `.append()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
path = (some path...)
files = [path+x for x in ['FILESLIST']]

for i in files:
    with open(i, 'r') as j:
        Reader = csv.reader(j)
        List.append([L for L in Reader])
```